# Can you instantiate a Java class constructor with an untyped object?

Tags: java, class, constructor

I'm coming from a Javascript background. I understand that in Java, to instantiate a class, you can provide multiple constructors to set the class variables. However, can you provide the constructor with an untyped object to initialise the class variables like below:

```
public class Book {
    String title;
    String author;

    public Book(Object data) {
        this.title = data.title;
        this.author = data.author;
    }
}
```

So can I instantiate a new Book instance like:

```
Book bookOne = new Book({ title: "Book One", author: "Author One" });
```

The reason why I want to do this is because if a class has let's say more than 10 variables to be when initialised, it's difficult to instantiate a class reliably by giving a list of let's say 10 parameters.

Comment: No, you cannot. `Object` doesn't have the `title` and `author` fields.

Comment: Then that means if I want to set 10 class variables during the instantiation, I will have to create a constructor which takes in 10 arguments. Is this correct?

Comment: Technically you can, but you'd have to rely on reflection to copy the relevant fields. That is not how you'd generally work in Java.

Comment: In Java, one would use the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for this. It lets you write `Book bookOne = new BookBuilder().setTitle("Book One").setAuthor("Author One").build()`. And you can auto-generate such builders using [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by relying on a JSON api and by specifying a `String` instead of an `Object` as parameter.
But that is not type safe and it is an anti pattern in Java that is strongly typed.
Note that when you communicate between a JavaScript frontend and a Java backend it is of course acceptable to receive JSON in Java.  But generally we don't manipulate the JSON directly. It is deserialiazed in an instance of a specific class which fields represents information transmitted by the JSON.

> the reason why I want to do this is because if a class has let's say
>   more than 10 variables to be when initialised, it's difficult to
>   instantiate a class reliably by giving a list of let's say 10
>   parameters

A class constructor with 10 parameters is not a good pattern either.
While in some cases, it may be acceptable to set 10 fields to an instance : especially as the class represents only a data structure.
In this case the best way to set the fields of the object is either using a setter or a builder.

1) Setter way

```
Book b = new Book();
b.setTitle(...);
b.setAuthor(...);
```

2) Builder way

```
Book b = new Book.BookBuilder()
                 .withTitle(...)
                 .withAuthor(...)
                 .build();
```

But really avoid the constructor that is error prone because of parameter types that could be misplaced and the construction invocation readability that will suffer too.

Comment: I like the second one I usually use lombok in such cases https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder

Comment: @YCF_L Excellent adding. Personally I don't use often lombok for that as I like coding myself the builders but I think that I have to stop that :)

Comment: Good job mentioning the builder pattern I reckon

Comment: Yes @davidxxx your code can be Just like this https://ideone.com/HdIejR ;)

Comment: @YCF_L thank you so much for this. It's very helpful for a Java beginner. So you're saying that these annotations Getter, Setter, AllArgsConstructor, NoArgsConstructor and Builder(toBuilder = true) essentially add all the relevant getter, setter, constructor and builder methods to my class? This sounds like a dream. :D

Comment: @Sorakthun Ly Note that defining both setter `AND` builder for a class defeat in a some way the builder intention : consistency (state, thread safety) and immutability of the created object.

Comment: @SorakthunLy for a beginner I would use simple getter setter and create my own Builder instead of using lombok ;)

Comment: @YCF_L I'm a Javascript developer, so I tend to look for shortcuts just like any developer does but I will keep your suggestion in mind :D